# UIFont lineheight and leading value changed between iOS6 and iOS7

Tags: ios, uitextview, cgcontext, uifont

I am using xcode 5, while using setting font to textview and i am drawing lines using `CGContext` and i found some weird issue the value of `font.lineHeight` changing between iOS6 and iOS7.

for example, in iOS6 `font.lineHeight` = 25.000000 but
             in iOS7 `font.lineHeight` = 21.850000

So the lines are not drawing properly in textview.

This is my code, Note: `self` is `UITextview`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:19];
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

//Get the current drawing context   
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
//Set the line color and width
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.784 green:0.675 blue:0.576 alpha:1.0].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
//Start a new Path
CGContextBeginPath(context);

//Find the number of lines in our textView + add a bit more height to draw lines in the empty part of the view
NSUInteger numberOfLines = (self.contentSize.height + self.bounds.size.height) / self.font.lineHeight;

//Set the line offset from the baseline. (I'm sure there's a concrete way to calculate this.)
CGFloat baselineOffset = 3.5f;

//iterate over numberOfLines and draw each line
for (int x = 0; x < numberOfLines; x++) {
    //0.5f offset lines up line with pixel boundary
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.font.lineHeight*x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.font.lineHeight*x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);

}

//Close our Path and Stroke (draw) it
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: Check line height by change some of other font. I had same problem.

Comment: I changed some other fonts and i am getting the same issue

Comment: check with system font..

Comment: I wasted 1 days in resolving this issue and I didn't any correct solution. At last I used padding some more point to resolve the issue. But for me when I change the some other font, I was getting correct value.

Comment: Even I set the system font and cant get any correct value,..

Comment: I replace fontlineheight with fontLeading and i use this one line in iOS7.. self.layoutManager.usesFontLeading = NO; Now its working fine,..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a screenshot of several lines of 19pt Helvetica in an iOS7 `UILabel`. As you can see, there are 88px (non-retina) between two Ls spaced 4 lines apart. Since, 88 / 4 = 22, it would appear that 21.85 is indeed the correct line spacing.

Are you getting different results?

If the spacing changed from 25 to 22 between iOS6 and iOS7, I would guess Apple modified the font metrics in overhauling the look and feel of the OS.

[image]

Comment: Now what can i do,.. i need to draw lines,.. Is there any way to get the lineheight like iOS6..

Comment: If you need a number that has changed, it seems you would need to hard-code the old number in your app. Can you just multiply the line height by a constant like 1.14, e.g. 22 * 1.14 = 25? Otherwise, I think you need to express your problem in more general terms and maybe post some images to clarify what it is you want.

Comment: I replace fontlineheight with fontLeading and i use this one line in iOS7.. self.layoutManager.usesFontLeading = NO; Now its working fine,..

Comment: @rajath set textview.layoutManager.usesFontleading = NO; for iOS7 you can get the exact leading value that produce in iOS6,.. You can try this,..